# Only 100 device can be added to developer certificate, any other way?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad

I need to add more than 100 devices to Apple Developer Program. They are not accepting more than.

- Is there any way or update, to add more than 100 device in a year?

**EDIT :** 
we already added 98 devices. we need to test our apps/games on new devices (iPhone5/iPod5).

- Any idea?

Comment: you can buy 2 apple developer program

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you don't need it (and you can't do it).  Unless you are building an in house application, in which case you need an Enterprise License.

Comment: we already added 98 devices. we need to test our apps/games on new devices (iPhone5/iPod5). Any fruitful idea?

Comment: Remove some of the old devices, and wait a year.  Or switch to Enterprise.

Comment: @borrrden: How does Test Flight solve this problem? You still need to code-sign for all these devices.

Comment: @Thilo Do you?  I thought the whole appeal of it was that you didn't have to care about the device limit.

Comment: @Thilo Yes, I still need to code-sign for all these devices

Comment: It seems I misunderstood what test-flight was.  In that case, Paul Lynch's suggestion is the only valid one.

Answer (score 2):

The only option that you have is buying a 2nd developer license.

As stated [here](https://developer.apple.com/programs/start/ios/) the Enterprise License it's **not** good because:

- you need to have a company
- you need to have your own distribution system and provide personal informations
- you are not able to distribute the app outside your *internal* distribution system, this mean *no apple store* for an Enterprise License.